# Arduino Serial Port with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, arduino, serial-port

I got an Arduino Sketch which writes some binary data to the serial port.
Something like:

```
0110101010010

01010100011011110

10101000110
```

These codes can have different lengths. **Now I need a bash script which reads the serial output line by line,shows the read codes together with a spinner and appends the codes to a textfile.**

This is what i came up with: (relevant parts of the script)

```
spinner()
{
    local pid=$1
    local delay=0.2
    local spinstr='|/-\'
    while [ "$(ps a | awk '{print $1}' | grep $pid)" ]; do
        local temp=${spinstr#?}
        printf " [%c]  " "$spinstr"
        local spinstr=$temp${spinstr%"$temp"}
        sleep $delay
        printf "\b\b\b\b\b\b"
    done
    printf "    \b\b\b\b"
}

function monitor {
    trap ctrl_c INT
    echo "Starting Monitor Mode"
    echo "Receiving..."
    stty -f $1 raw speed 9600
    ( cat $1 ) & spinner $!
}

function ctrl_c() {
        echo -e "\nAborting. Collected keys were saved."
                #save keys
                exit 0
}
```

The method to show a spinner is taken from : http://fitnr.com/showing-a-bash-spinner.html.

Actually I am trying to read the serial output with these two commands:

```
stty -f $1 raw speed 9600
( cat $1 >> $keyfile) & spinner $!
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Here is a sample screenshot of codes that i send:

[image: correct codes]

This is the output I am getting :

[image: wrong codes]

Can you help me correct my code that desired behaviour (marked as bold) can be accomplished ?

**EDIT:** Nevermind I got it working by myself with the help of this:

```
( tee -a < $1 $keyfile ) & spinner $!
```